# Solucionar problema de seguridad de base de datos y php

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

soy nuevo acá y tengo un problema con mi página, resulta que tiene registro de usuario, sesión y administrador, si entro con mi cuenta de admin, puedo borrar o editar usuarios, le problema es que, al entrar en admin, aparece una sección llamada "Usuarios" donde entro y me aparece la lista de usuarios registrados, pero si copio la URL(http://localhost/bib-t1r/abm_p.php) de esa sección y entro sin mi cuenta de admin, puedo entrar sin que se me prohiba la entrada y borrar todo lo que quiera, realmente no sé que agregar o modificar para solucionar el error de seguridad.

```
    <?php
@$_COOKIE['aux_d'];

if(@$_COOKIE['aux_d'] == 2)
{
include_once("libreria/persona.php");

$datos = new Persona();
$persona = new Persona();

include_once("menu_bs.php");

$operacion = '';

$nombre = '';
$apellido = '';
$sexo = '';
$dni = '';
$carrera = '';
$telefono='';
$email='';
$user='';
$rol='';

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $operacion = isset($_GET['operacion']) ? $_GET['operacion'] : 'alta' ;
    if ($operacion == 'alta' && !isset($_GET['id_pers'])){
        $persona->nombre=$_POST['txtNombre'];
        $persona->apellido=$_POST['txtApellido'];
        $persona->sexo=$_POST['txtSexo'];
        $persona->dni=$_POST['txtDni'];
        $persona->carrera=$_POST['txtCarrera'];
        $persona->telefono=$_POST['txtTelefono'];
        $persona->email=$_POST['txtEmail'];
        $persona->user=$_POST['txtUser'];
        $persona->rol=$_POST['txtRol'];
        if($_POST['txtPass'] != "" && $_POST['txtPass1'] != "" && ($_POST['txtPass'] == $_POST['txtPass1'])){
          $persona->passwd=$_POST['txtPass'];
        }
        else{
        $persona->passwd="";
        }           
        $persona->guardar();
    }
    if ($operacion == 'actualizar' && isset($_GET['id_pers'])){
        echo '2-actualizar';
        $persona->nombre=$_POST['txtNombre'];
        $persona->apellido=$_POST['txtApellido'];
        $persona->sexo=$_POST['txtSexo'];
        $persona->dni=$_POST['txtDni'];
        $persona->carrera=$_POST['txtCarrera'];
        $persona->telefono=$_POST['txtTelefono'];
        $persona->email=$_POST['txtEmail'];
        $persona->user=$_POST['txtUser'];
        $persona->rol=$_POST['txtRol'];
        if($_POST['txtPass'] != "" && $_POST['txtPass1'] != "" && ($_POST['txtPass'] == $_POST['txtPass1'])){
          $persona->passwd=$_POST['txtPass'];
        }
        else{
          $persona->passwd="";
        }       
        $persona->actualizar($_GET['id_pers']);
        header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }
    if ($operacion == 'borrar' && isset($_GET['id_pers'])){
        $persona->borrar($_GET['id_pers']);
    }
    if ($operacion == 'edicion' && isset($_GET['id_usuario'])) {
        $id_usuario = $_GET['id_usuario'];
        $datos=Persona::traer_datos($id_usuario);
        $nombre = $datos['nombre'];
        $apellido = $datos['apellido'];
        $sexo = $datos['sexo'];
        $dni = $datos['dni'];
        $carrera = $datos['carrera'];
    } 
}
?>
<script src="bootstrap/js/funciones_p.js"></script> 
<div class="container-fluid">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation" >  
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 0px;">
      <span style="padding-right: 20px;font-weight: bold;">Usuarios</span>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm"   onclick="cargar('#capa_d','alta_p.php')">Alta</button>
      </ul>        
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 0px;">
        <input type="text"  id="txt_b" placeholder="Buscar" style="position: absolute;right: 100px;" >
        <button type="button" id="btn_b" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="position: absolute;right: 20px;">Buscar</button>
      </ul>     
     </div>  
   </nav>
 </div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
  <div id="capa_d">
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
  <div id="capa_L"> 
        </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}else{echo 'Usted no tiene permitido el acceso a esta seccion';}
?>
```

Desde ya muchas gracias. Y disculpen, es mi primera vez que armo una página así.

Comment: Almacenas en sesión el tipo de usuario que es??

Comment: Tengo un "if ( isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['userid']) && $_SESSION['username'] != '' && $_SESSION['userid'] != '0' )"  En login.php

Comment: Mira la respuesta, a ver si te funcina

Comment: Al agregarlo, al ingresar con admin logeado aparece: Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\bib-t1r\abm_p.php on line 8     Y sin el admin logeado es el mismo error

Comment: Claro, cuando inicias session debes poner el valor en la session, por ejemplo, if(esta_logueado){ $_SESSION['tipo_usuario']==$tipo_usuario;}

Comment: Lo del ejemplo, en dónde iria?

Comment: Donde hagas el inicio de session, cuando le das  valor a $_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['userid']... seria $_SESSION['tipo_usuairo'] = tipo_usuario_sacado_de_base_de_datos;

Comment: if ( isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['userid']) && $_SESSION['username'] != '' && $_SESSION['userid'] != '0' && ($_SESSION['username']!='admin' ) lo agregué y sigue sin funcionar, hice algo mal

Comment: No, no me refiero a que lo pongas ahí, si no donde inicias sesión, en la parte de tu aplicación que buscas el usuario en base de datos para ver si existe o no y metes en $_SESSION el nombre, id...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si almacenas en session el tipo de usuario que es, puedes poner el siguiente código en tu página abm_p.php :

```
if($_SESSION['tipo_usuario']!='admin'){
    echo 'Usted no tiene permitido el acceso a esta seccion';
    die;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Auxiliate de la opción `header location`

El siguiente script lo debes colocar en todas las páginas que necesites proteger de inicios de sesión restringidos

### SOBRE HEADER LOCATION

> Header location enviará los encabezados HTTP del mismo modo te aclaro
>   que es mejor que la URL a la cual vas a redirigir al usuario de
>   preferencia sea la absoluta para que todos los navegadores la
>   interpreten del modo correcto

Del modo siguiente

```
if($_SESSION['tipo_usuario']!='admin'){
    header('Location: http://web.com/login.php');
}
```

Se usa die para que inmediatamente que se valida que la sesión no se corresponda se mata la ejecución del script

> Con header location, lo que hacemos es pasarle la url de la página que
>   le vamos a mostrar al usuario una vez que se valida que la sesión no
>   es la indicada para un determinado usuario